What kind of vehicle is this? (tracked amphibious vehicle)
What kind of vehicle is this?
It looks like some sort of tracked amphibious vehicle. I'd like to know the name of it so I can research it.




Is this suitable for this site? I think great outdoors = self propelled, not mechanical monsters.

Let's not get too purist.

It looks like it's a ARGO FRONTIER EFI 6X6:
https://www.argoadventure.com/ARGO-FRONTIER-EFI-6X6_p_12818.html
Aka a 6x6 Amphibious ATV.

I am surprised that the 700cc and 750cc versions produce only 19hp and 23hp respectively. And with a water speed of 3mph can't candle much of a current.

@WeatherVane Apparently that is common for engines designed to produce high torque - tractors etc., and presumably this vehicle too, to have low HP for the CC value. The high torque means you are less likely to get stuck as the wheels will keep putting out a lot of power at low RPM, so you can grind your way out of mud etc rather than spinning your wheels uselessly at high(er) RPM.
